# Prevent button event from being fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, cross-browser

I know there is the Sharepoint portal, but in my opinion, this question is more related to javascript and cross browsing than to Sharepoint.

I have a custom ribbon button in Sharepoint which should start a workflow on a specific element in my library. I want to add a javascript/jquery check to verify some data and only if everything is fine, the button event should fire up.

```
<a unselectable="on" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" class="ms-cui-ctl-large " mscui:controltype="Button" role="button" id="AddNewButton-Large"><span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer"><span unselectable="on" class=" ms-cui-img-32by32 ms-cui-img-cont-float"><img unselectable="on" alt="Neue Testmappe erstellen" src="http://contoso:43265/sites/contoso/_layouts/Images/docset_captureversion_32.png" style="left: 0px;"></span></span><span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel">Create Element<br>erstellen</span></a>
```

Tried everything, but the event is always firing. Also tried .unbind() or .off() methods and the .preventDefault(). Really dont know how to prevent the event from being fired.

Are there any special cross browser events that I should be aware of when trying to prevent from firing the event?

I can see the events in developer tools on my "a" element. And when I remove the events, everything works (or not). But it is impossible to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [preventdefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //and now do stuff like for example:
  $('body').hide();

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working and still firing my event

Comment: Hmm. then i think you've tried it all (unbind, off, return false), maybe sharepoint blocks this kind of code?

Comment: Maybe there are some events bound to the element or the way they are fired is different the normal model?

Answer (score 1):

In your onclick attribute, use a function:

```
function(event){ event.preventDefault(); }
```

As an alternative, you can write some javascript that will stop it:

with JQuery:

```
$("a").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //any function that you need ...
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working and still firing my event

Comment: are you sure this is not span that has event triggered?

Comment: Actually I am not. How can I find out?

Comment: You cab use Google Chrome inspector, once you select span element, you can go to event listeners section and check if it has onclick function

Comment: The exact selector for the specific event is the a#AddNewButton-Large.ms-cui-ctl-large. So, no, it is not on the span element.